# How to access nested resource parameters from parent controller in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-resources

I started writing an app which reviews books, articles etc(model name: Piece ) and has the option to review chapters or smaller sections (Sections, Subsections, and Subsubsections models)

I want to be able to generate a general overview of the Piece where all of the nested Sections, Subsections, and Subsubsections and their attributes will be listed in one view. So my routes.rb file looks like this:

```
  resources :pieces do
     resources :sections do
       resources :subsections do 
         resources :subsubsections
       end
     end
   end
```

Which I have since learned is sloppy but its too late for me now. 
For now, I have been able to do this from the subsubsections, because it has acces to all the parent parameters (piece_id, section_id, etc). But this means that I have to jump down the tree into the Subsubsection view and then go from there, whereas I would like to be able to access all these parameters from the Piece controller so that I can link straight from the Piece view to the more general overview, without having to go all the way down the chain.

I apologize if this is a simple question, I only started recently.

My models like like this:

```
class Subsubsection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subsection
end

class Subsection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :subsubsections
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :piece
    has_many :subsections
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sections
    has_many :links
end
```

And the way i am accessing the general overview for now is using the index action of the subsubsections controller:

```
def index
    @piece = Piece.find(params[:piece_id])
    @section = @piece.sections.find(params[:section_id])
    @subsection = @section.subsections.find(params[:subsection_id])
end
```

My view accesses it like this:

```
<p><%= link_to "'General Piece Overview", piece_section_subsection_subsubsections_path(@piece, @section, @subsection), class: 'section_name' %></p>
```

Heres the link to the project in case it helps:

https://github.com/kingdavidek/StuddyBuddy

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some internal tension; you say you want access to the nested parameters from your `PieceController`, but if the request has been routed to `PieceController`, those nested parameters will not be present.  When nested parameters are present, the request will be routed to the most specific controller class for which the request provides a parameter.

If the question can be rephrased as "how, from within `PieceController` can I generate something like a table of contents?" the answer looks something like this.

In `PieceController`:

```
def show
  @piece = Piece.find(params[:id]).include(sections: {subsections: :subsubsections}})
end
```

In `app/views/pieces/show.html.erb`

```
<% @piece.sections.each do |section| %>
  <%= link_to piece_section_path(@piece, section), section.title %>
  <% section.subsections.each do |subsection| %>
    <%= link_to piece_section_subsection_path(@piece, section, subsection), subsection.title %>
    <% subsection.subsubsections.each do |subsubsection| %>
      <%= link_to piece_section_subsection_subsubsection_path(@piece, section, subsection, subsubsection), subsubsection.title %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This makes some assumptions, but hopefully the idea is clear.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! As I understand, it is not possible to do what I was doing originally, which is fine. I tried to implement what you where doing by using the includes method but i get a **"NoMethodError in PiecesController#show", undefined method `includes' for #<Piece:0x000000048936f0>.**  Do you have any idea why this is?